# Got Software causes connection abort while using mobaxterm to connect to EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, connection, mobaxterm

I have 4 EC2 instances and 1 AliYun instance, they all work well if I connect to them using ssh from the command line.
However, when connecting to EC2 instances using mobaxterm, they get stuck and throw `Software cause connection abort` within 0-5 minutes (Sometimes, I can't even type a command completely before getting this message).
What should I do to avoid this problem or which other tools can I use instead of mobaxterm?